# how can I send a data by ajax and the url has a variable value in the middle of the link

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am using this API:'/api/categories/${catID}/items/addItem/'

from my spring boot java to enter some data to item table which has relation with category table.

Now in javascript, I used ajax:
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/categories/${catID}/items/addItem/',
         type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        etc

Now I get a problem from the url and cannot read the value of ${catID}

This is the real API: "/api/categories/{categoryId}/items/addItem"
I have looked inside the site but the solution does not work with me.
Now how can I pass a value of a variable if the variable are in the middle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: string replace before the call might help you

Comment: Use a template literal.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you , I tried this way: '/api/categories/ '+ categoryId +'/items/addItem' and worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use template literals which require backticks(`) instead of single quotes(').

```
url: `/api/categories/${catID}/items/addItem/`
```